# Zsh repeats command in output

Tags: zsh, zshrc

My apologies if this is a repetition of a question already asked. I looked at the questions asked similar to mine and tried the solutions but nothing is working.

I am on Ubuntu and am using zsh with oh-my-zsh on terminal. If I type the command `ls`, for example it firsts outputs something like this `%ls` as the first line of the of the output. This is distracting and I want to get rid of it.

Here is an example:

[Screenshot on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yTwR.png)

Here is my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH=/home/user/.oh-my-zsh

# Set name of the theme to load.
# Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# Optionally, if you set this to "random", it'll load a random theme    each
# time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
ZSH_THEME="agnoster"
#default user
DEFAULT_USER=""

# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set to this to use case-sensitive completion
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Comment this out to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment to change how often before auto-updates occur? (in days)
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable colors in ls
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable autosetting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable command autocorrection
# DISABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want red dots to be displayed while waiting for completion
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable marking untracked files under
# VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories much,
# much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# Customize to your needs...
export    PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/core_perl:~/Programs/android-studio/bin:~/Dropbox/www/laravel/vendor/bin
      LS_COLORS='bd=38;5;68:ca=38;5;17:cd=38;5;113;1:di=38;5;30:do=38;5;127:ex=38;5;166;1:pi=38;5;126:fi=38;5;253:ln=target:mh=38;5;220;1:or=48;5;196;38;5;232;1:ow=38;5;220;1:sg=48;5;234;38;5;100;1:su=38;5;137:so=38;5;197:st=38;5;86;48;5;234:tw=48;5;235;38;5;139;3:*LS_COLORS=48;5;89;38;5;197;1;3;4;7:*.BAT=38;5;108:*.PL=38;5;160:*.asm=38;5;240;1:*.awk=38;5;148;1:*.bash=38;5;173:*.bat=38;5;108:*.c=38;5;110:*.cc=38;5;24;1:*.ii=38;5;24;1:*.cfg=1:*.cl=38;5;204;1:*.coffee=38;5;94;1:*.conf=1:*.C=38;5;24;1:*.cp=38;5;24;1:*.cpp=38;5;24;1:*.cxx=38;5;24;1:*.c++=38;5;24;1:*.ii=38;5;24;1:*.cs=38;5;74;1:*.css=38;5;91:*.csv=38;5;78:*.ctp=38;5;95:*.diff=48;5;197;38;5;232:*.enc=38;5;192;3:*.eps=38;5;192:*.etx=38;5;172:*.ex=38;5;148;1:*.example=38;5;225;1:*.git=38;5;197:*.gitignore=38;5;240:*.go=38;5;36;1:*.h=38;5;81:*.H=38;5;81:*.hpp=38;5;81:*.hxx=38;5;81:*.h++=38;5;81:*.tcc=38;5;81:*.f=38;5;81:*.for=38;5;81:*.ftn=38;5;81:*.s=38;5;81:*.S=38;5;81:*.sx=38;5;81:*.hi=38;5;240:*.hs=38;5;155;1:*.htm=38;5;125;1:*.html=38;5;125;1:*.info=38;5;101:*.ini=38;5;122:*.java=38;5;142;1:*.jhtm=38;5;125;1:*.js=38;5;42:*.jsm=38;5;42:*.jsm=38;5;42:*.json=38;5;199:*.jsp=38;5;45:*.lisp=38;5;204;1:*.log=38;5;190:*.lua=38;5;34;1:*.m=38;5;130;3:*.mht=38;5;129:*.mm=38;5;130;3:*.M=38;5;130;3:*.map=38;5;58;3:*.markdown=38;5;184:*.md=38;5;184:*.mf=38;5;220;3:*.mfasl=38;5;73:*.mi=38;5;124:*.mkd=38;5;184:*.mtx=38;5;36;3:*.nfo=38;5;220:*.o=38;5;240:*.pacnew=38;5;33:*.patch=48;5;197;38;5;232;1:*.pc=38;5;100:*.pfa=38;5;43:*.pgsql=38;5;222:*.php=38;5;93:*.pl=38;5;214:*.plt=38;5;204;1:*.pm=38;5;197;1:*.pod=38;5;172;1:*.py=38;5;41:*.pyc=38;5;240:*.rb=38;5;192:*.rdf=38;5;144:*.rst=38;5;67:*.ru=38;5;142:*.scm=38;5;204;1:*.sed=38;5;130;1:*.sfv=38;5;197:*.sh=38;5;113:*.signature=38;5;206:*.sql=38;5;222:*.srt=38;5;116:*.sty=38;5;58:*.sug=38;5;44:*.t=38;5;28;1:*.tcl=38;5;64;1:*.tdy=38;5;214:*.tex=38;5;172:*.textile=38;5;106:*.tfm=38;5;64:*.tfnt=38;5;140:*.theme=38;5;109:*.txt=38;5;192:*.urlview=38;5;85:*.vim=1:*.viminfo=38;5;240;1:*.xml=38;5;199:*.yml=38;5;208:*.zsh=38;5;173:*README=38;5;220;1:*Makefile=38;5;196:*MANIFEST=38;5;243:*pm_to_blib=38;5;240:*.1=38;5;196;1:*.3=38;5;196;1:*.7=38;5;196;1:*.1p=38;5;160:*.3p=38;5;160:*.am=38;5;242:*.in=38;5;242:*.old=38;5;242:*.out=38;5;46;1:*.bmp=38;5;62:*.cdr=38;5;59:*.gif=38;5;72:*.ico=38;5;73:*.jpeg=38;5;66:*.jpg=38;5;66:*.JPG=38;5;66:*.png=38;5;68;1:*.svg=38;5;24;1:*.xpm=38;5;36:*.32x=38;5;137:*.A64=38;5;82:*.a00=38;5;11:*.a52=38;5;112:*.a64=38;5;82:*.a78=38;5;112:*.adf=38;5;35:*.atr=38;5;213:*.cdi=38;5;124:*.fm2=38;5;35:*.gb=38;5;203:*.gba=38;5;205:*.gbc=38;5;204:*.gel=38;5;83:*.gg=38;5;138:*.ggl=38;5;83:*.j64=38;5;102:*.nds=38;5;193:*.nes=38;5;160:*.rom=38;5;59;1:*.sav=38;5;220:*.sms=38;5;33:*.st=38;5;208;1:*.iso=38;5;124:*.nrg=38;5;124:*.qcow=38;5;141:*.VOB=38;5;137:*.IFO=38;5;240:*.BUP=38;5;241:*.MOV=38;5;42:*.3gp=38;5;134:*.3g2=38;5;133:*.asf=38;5;25:*.avi=38;5;114:*.divx=38;5;112:*.f4v=38;5;125:*.flv=38;5;131:*.m2v=38;5;166:*.mkv=38;5;202:*.mov=38;5;42:*.mp4=38;5;124:*.mpg=38;5;38:*.mpeg=38;5;38:*.ogm=38;5;97:*.ogv=38;5;94:*.rmvb=38;5;112:*.sample=38;5;130;1:*.ts=38;5;39:*.vob=38;5;137:*.webm=38;5;109:*.wmv=38;5;113:*.S3M=38;5;71;1:*.aac=38;5;137:*.cue=38;5;112:*.dat=38;5;165:*.dts=38;5;100;1:*.fcm=38;5;41:*.flac=38;5;166;1:*.m3u=38;5;172:*.m3u8=38;5;172:*.m4=38;5;196;3:*.m4a=38;5;137;1:*.mid=38;5;102:*.midi=38;5;102:*.mod=38;5;72:*.mp3=38;5;191:*.oga=38;5;95:*.ogg=38;5;96:*.s3m=38;5;71;1:*.sid=38;5;69;1:*.spl=38;5;173:*.wv=38;5;149:*.wvc=38;5;149:*.afm=38;5;58:*.pfb=38;5;58:*.pfm=38;5;58:*.ttf=38;5;66:*.pcf=38;5;65:*.psf=38;5;64:*.bak=38;5;41;1:*.bin=38;5;249:*.pid=38;5;160:*.state=38;5;124:*.swo=38;5;236:*.swp=38;5;241:*.tmp=38;5;244:*.un~=38;5;240:*.zcompdump=38;5;240:*.zwc=38;5;240:*.db=38;5;60:*.dump=38;5;119:*.sqlite=38;5;60:*.typelib=38;5;60:*.7z=38;5;40:*.a=38;5;46:*.apk=38;5;172;3:*.arj=38;5;41:*.bz2=38;5;44:*.deb=38;5;215:*.ipk=38;5;117:*.jad=38;5;50:*.jar=38;5;51:*.nth=38;5;40:*.sis=38;5;39:*.part=38;5;239;1:*.r00=38;5;239:*.r01=38;5;239:*.r02=38;5;239:*.r03=38;5;239:*.r04=38;5;239:*.r05=38;5;239:*.r06=38;5;239:*.r07=38;5;239:*.r08=38;5;239:*.r09=38;5;239:*.r10=38;5;239:*.r100=38;5;239:*.r101=38;5;239:*.r102=38;5;239:*.r103=38;5;239:*.r104=38;5;239:*.r105=38;5;239:*.r106=38;5;239:*.r107=38;5;239:*.r108=38;5;239:*.r109=38;5;239:*.r11=38;5;239:*.r110=38;5;239:*.r111=38;5;239:*.r112=38;5;239:*.r113=38;5;239:*.r114=38;5;239:*.r115=38;5;239:*.r116=38;5;239:*.r12=38;5;239:*.r13=38;5;239:*.r14=38;5;239:*.r15=38;5;239:*.r16=38;5;239:*.r17=38;5;239:*.r18=38;5;239:*.r19=38;5;239:*.r20=38;5;239:*.r21=38;5;239:*.r22=38;5;239:*.r25=38;5;239:*.r26=38;5;239:*.r27=38;5;239:*.r28=38;5;239:*.r29=38;5;239:*.r30=38;5;239:*.r31=38;5;239:*.r32=38;5;239:*.r33=38;5;239:*.r34=38;5;239:*.r35=38;5;239:*.r36=38;5;239:*.r37=38;5;239:*.r38=38;5;239:*.r39=38;5;239:*.r40=38;5;239:*.r41=38;5;239:*.r42=38;5;239:*.r43=38;5;239:*.r44=38;5;239:*.r45=38;5;239:*.r46=38;5;239:*.r47=38;5;239:*.r48=38;5;239:*.r49=38;5;239:*.r50=38;5;239:*.r51=38;5;239:*.r52=38;5;239:*.r53=38;5;239:*.r54=38;5;239:*.r55=38;5;239:*.r56=38;5;239:*.r57=38;5;239:*.r58=38;5;239:*.r59=38;5;239:*.r60=38;5;239:*.r61=38;5;239:*.r62=38;5;239:*.r63=38;5;239:*.r64=38;5;239:*.r65=38;5;239:*.r66=38;5;239:*.r67=38;5;239:*.r68=38;5;239:*.r69=38;5;239:*.r69=38;5;239:*.r70=38;5;239:*.r71=38;5;239:*.r72=38;5;239:*.r73=38;5;239:*.r74=38;5;239:*.r75=38;5;239:*.r76=38;5;239:*.r77=38;5;239:*.r78=38;5;239:*.r79=38;5;239:*.r80=38;5;239:*.r81=38;5;239:*.r82=38;5;239:*.r83=38;5;239:*.r84=38;5;239:*.r85=38;5;239:*.r86=38;5;239:*.r87=38;5;239:*.r88=38;5;239:*.r89=38;5;239:*.r90=38;5;239:*.r91=38;5;239:*.r92=38;5;239:*.r93=38;5;239:*.r94=38;5;239:*.r95=38;5;239:*.r96=38;5;239:*.r97=38;5;239:*.r98=38;5;239:*.r99=38;5;239:*.rar=38;5;106;1:*.tar=38;5;118:*.tar.gz=38;5;34:*.tgz=38;5;35;1:*.xz=38;5;118:*.zip=38;5;41:*.pdf=38;5;203:*.djvu=38;5;141:*.cbr=38;5;140:*.cbz=38;5;140:*.chm=38;5;144:*.odt=38;5;111:*.ods=38;5;112:*.odp=38;5;166:*.odb=38;5;161:*.allow=38;5;112:*.deny=38;5;196:*.SKIP=38;5;244:*.def=38;5;136:*.directory=38;5;83:*.err=38;5;160;1:*.error=38;5;160;1:*.pi=38;5;126:*.properties=38;5;197;1:*.torrent=38;5;58:*.gp3=38;5;114:*.gp4=38;5;115:*.tg=38;5;99:*.pcap=38;5;29:*.cap=38;5;29:*.dmp=38;5;29:*.service=38;5;81:*@.service=38;5;45:*.socket=38;5;75:*.device=38;5;24:*.mount=38;5;115:*.automount=38;5;114:*.swap=38;5;113:*.target=38;5;73:*.path=38;5;116:*.timer=38;5;111:*.snapshot=38;5;139:';
export LS_COLORS

# Function to switch and save the current path
function cd() {
  builtin cd "$@";
  echo "$PWD" > ~/.cwd;
}
export cd
alias cwd='cd "$(cat ~/.cwd)"'
export TERM=screen-256color-bce
```

I would appreciate any pointer to how to solve this.

Comment: Problem description too vague, not informative at all. Does this only happen to `ls`? Please at least post some sample commands and outputs.

Comment: I tried `setopt no_verbose`. It did not work, thanks.

Comment: My guess is there's some preexec hook trying to set the window title to the command being executed using terminal escape codes, but your terminal doesn't support that, so it's printed. Do `setopt xtrace` to see what's going on. Also, try to set your terminal to `xterm` (or `xterm-256color`).

Comment: As mentioned, this does look like the `verbose` option is at play: it will repeat the command executed. Try not sourcing oh-my-zsh and see if you still get the behavior. You should simply run `setopt` to see what has been set, and look for `verbose` (or others). A behavior similar to `verbose` is history expansion. When active, it will re-print the fully expanded command.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

uncomment `DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"`

Comment: Great! Thank you for this, but do you know why works?

Comment: [oh-my-zsh/termsupport.zsh at master · robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/lib/termsupport.zsh#L25)
I guess there's some bugs in the function of handling title of terminal.
Refs: [AUTO_TITLE functionality breaks in tmux · Issue #3579 · robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/3579)